# OutOfMemoryError when adding imageView programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

I want to add a few `ImageView` in a `linearLayout` programmatically.
but application crashed for more than 2 images. its error is **OutOfMemoryError.**

```
String[] titleImages={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
for (String title : titleImages){

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets()
                .open("titles"+"/"+title);
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        inputStream.close();

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        //more imageView set properties
        LinearLayout shelf=findViewById(R.id.shelf);
        //shelf is a LinearLayout
        shelf.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: use try catch. to handle outofmemory

Comment: @AshwinSAshok it's an error, not exception. Subclass of  `Error` shouldn't be caught in most cases, and `OutOfMemoryError` is among them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use smaller images.

Or, use `BitmapFactory.Options`, an in particular its `inSampleSize` option, to downsample the images to something that is more appropriate for your screen size.

Or, use a third-party image-loading library, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), that can handle `inSampleSize` for you.

Comment: any OutOfMemoryException related to Bitmaps/Images should be not answered anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

by using these methods you can resize the image as per your use.

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

```
// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
```

}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

```
if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
```

}